# Vim Command Line Escape Timeout

Tags: vim

I'm having an issue with a delay when using `<Esc>` or `<C-[>` to get out of command line mode.  It appears that vim is waiting to see if I'm going to enter a keymapping, and I've changed my ttimeoutlen and it doesn't change the delay but it's not really what I want.  I'd prefer not to have any delay

I've done a :map to see if there are any mappings that expect a `<Esc>`... or `<C-[>`... but don't see any that do.

Comment: You should check it out with the `:cmap`, which display the maps in command line mode.

Answer (score 7):

Along with setting ttimeoutlen, do you also set ttimeout?  This is needed to turn the feature on.  I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
set ttimeout
set ttimeoutlen=100
```

Now I get no delay after ESC (even when running without the GUI), even though I have maps that involve ESC.  For example:

```
if !has("gui_running")
    set <A-v>=<1b>v
endif

inoremap <A-v> <C-o>"+p
```

(note the <1b> above was written using "Ctrl-v ESC")

Comment: I have this set, but it appears to have no effect on command line mode.

Comment: Works for me, Mac/iTerm2 + Vim, even in Command-Line mode.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the comment @AdeYU posted on the question, the [vim reference for maps](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapmode-c) says there are three different kinds of mapping that can affect the command-line:

- :map
- :cmap
- :lmap

You'd have to check all three to rule out a mapping as the cause of your problem.

**Update:** Despite what the docs seem to indicate, if I create an imap that begins with escape, then hitting escape while in command-line mode does suddenly take longer to respond.  I guess you'd have to clear out the imaps too.

Comment: Running :map displays all mappings, with their mode in the far left column.

Comment: @KevinColyar That was the behavior I expected, too, but when I ran :map in vim 7.2 and 7.3 I didn't see the cmapping or the lmapping I had created.  Does vim behave differently when you try it out?

Comment: Ahh, you're right.  

Do you know if an imap would cause a timeout issue in command mode?

I found this mapping from delimitMate:  `<Esc>OC       <Right>`

Comment: @KevinColyar I wouldn't have guessed it, but my experimenting sure seems to indicate that insert mappings affect command-line mode.  I updated my answer accordingly.  

I guess the test you ought to make is to uninstall delimitMate and check if the problem goes away.

Comment: Tried removing delimitMate with no luck.  Tried removing all mappings with `:mapclear`, `:imapclear`, etc.  No dice, still get the delay.

Comment: To make sure I wasn't getting any custom behavior, I moved my .vim directory out of the way, created an empty vimrc, and started vim with the -u using that file.  Then I tried hitting <esc> in command-line mode and intentionally hitting `s` or `i` immediately afterward.  Doing that seemed to make vim enter a goofy archaic mode where it was taking insert mode input at the bottom of the screen until I hit ctrl-c.

Comment: Even without my .vimrc and my .vim directory I notice a bit of a delay between hitting <esc> and my cursor appearing back in my buffer.  I have a weird feeling it's some deep dark part of vi that I don't understand.  Hitting escape twice seems to bypass that delay.