# cmdline of vim on mac terminal or iTerm2 disappear very slow

Tags: vim

I type `:` and then type `esc` key to exit command mod, the cmdline disappear very slow, about 1s-2s, which actually you are in normal already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vim` is waiting a short time to allow for the possibility that the <kbd>esc</kbd> key might begin a special key (such as cursor-left or <kbd>F1</kbd>).

You can alter this behavior altering these settings: [`ttimeout`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27ttimeout%27), [`timeoutlen`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27timeoutlen%27)
and [`ttimeoutlen`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27timeoutlen%27).

The `timeoutlen` mode is set by default to 1 second (1000 milliseconds).  If you set that to a shorter time (0.1 seconds is fast), it will help.

Some suggest (as in vim's documentation) reducing the timeout, e.g.,

```
set ttimeout set ttimeoutlen=100
```

Related discussion:

- [Vim Command Line Escape Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399582/vim-command-line-escape-timeout)
- [Eliminating delays on ESC in vim and zsh](http://www.johnhawthorn.com/2012/09/vi-escape-delays/)